# Image have margin from top in constraintlayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-designer

I have a scrolled content, so I put a constraint layout inside a scrollview, I have a problem when put an image inside a constraint layout, but the image show a space from top such as in screenshot below, how can I remove that space?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <!-- have whatever children you want inside -->
        <ImageView
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/main_header"
                android:id="@+id/img_icon"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="#ffccbb"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1"
                android:contentDescription="TODO" app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Imageview` you have added `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"` that means it will take space 1:1, so width and height also will be 1:1. But your image `app:srcCompat="@drawable/main_header"` is not 1:1. So you have to add an image which has width and height of the same size. Otherwise, you can add           `android:scaleType="fitXY"` or `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` according to your expectation.

Comment: What must I change in my code to get my image at top with it's parent and fill width?

Comment: Add just android:scaleType="fitXY" and image will adjust with your image view width and height.

Comment: That is my Image, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OScROggogF0h_O3f4Evs9OWQ7zhukx9J/view , I want to be 25% of screen height, and fill width, I do not want to scaled.

Comment: You have to scale the image or have to change the ratio of width and height. If you don't want to scale, then change as 
 app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:8". It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked your code on my phone and it looks good.
 One thing that I made different from you is that I have used a different image resource for the imageView.

So I think that you don't actually have a problem, I think that it's just the image and how it looks, try to change your image resource and see if this problem remains.

**He is how my layout file looks like:**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_icon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/main_header"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What must I change in my code to get my image at top with it's parent and fill width?

Comment: Did you used another image?

Comment: Yes I use another one and it worked correctly, But I want to use that one as a header of my activity

Comment: Could you share your image itself?

Comment: That is my Image https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OScROggogF0h_O3f4Evs9OWQ7zhukx9J

Comment: Try to re-download your image because it worked just fine for me, maybe you have some other image as a resource by accident.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,  remove `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"`  in your `ImageView` it works!

Comment: What must I change in my code to get my image at top with it's parent and fill width?

Comment: in your imageview xml attribute , remove the line a wrote you above

Comment: I removed it, and Nothing changed.